# How do you use Puppeteer to work with the handle of a relative element

Tags: puppeteer

Given this

```
<div class="slot">
  <div class="label">
    <span>Name</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

or this

```
<div class="button">
  <span class="button-wrap">
    ...
    <span class="caption">Save</span>
  </span>
<div>
```

How do I work with elements relative to those I can identify? I am trying to test a third party product's web interface so have no control over the classes or identifiers assigned to the elements, and in many cases the elements are I want to work with are 'anonymous' and only distinguishable by elements relative to them.

This is what I've tried

```
const labelElement = page.evaluateHandle(
  () => {
    const labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slot'))
    return labels.find(label => label.textContent === 'Name')
  }
)
```

So this gets me the label element, but how do I get the sibling text input?

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to get a sibling element.

Use [.previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) to get just the previous element of the specific element, and [.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to get next immediate sibling element.

```
const specificLabel = labels.find(label => label.textContent === 'Name')
const previousElem = specificLabel.previousElementSibling;
const nextElem = specificLabel.nextElementSibling;
const parentElem = specificLabel.parentElement;
```

Comment: does this still work? i can't find any api in puppeteer which points to this. Can you please share with us where to find this api docs?

Comment: Added links to api.